# Is an employer rule mandating face coverings on their grounds enforceable even when employee is off work?

Tags: united-states, employment, maine

My employer (a private college in the US state of Maine) has a new rule mandating face coverings for employees, including in outdoor settings on their campus. The campus is open to the public to enjoy the grounds, and there is ***not*** a rule that the public must wear face coverings while on the grounds.

If I visit their grounds in my time off, am I breaking the rule if I do not wear a face covering?

Comment: FYI, I've glossed over a few details in the policy for the sake of a clear question.

Comment: Does the local governor's emergency orders *recommend* outdoor masks?  Generally those EOs permit authorities and companies to set a higher standard for their employees if they choose to.

Comment: House right might also be a relevant factor here. When the campus is private property of the college which they offer for public use out of their good will, then they have the right to set rules for its use by the public. The question is if they can create selective rules for using their campus which only apply to people who happen to be their employees.

Comment: @Philipp, that's kind of it, but I guess more to the point, do employee-specific rules legally apply to me when I'm not "on the clock"?

Comment: Maine is an [at-will employment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment) state; unless you have a contract that says otherwise, you can be fired at any time for any reason or no reason (with the exception of certain specific reasons like racial discrimination, etc).  This can certainly include firing for reasons having to do with your actions outside work hours, whether or not there is an explicit written rule about it.

Comment: So I think that what the law says may not be particularly relevant.  Practically speaking, what you really want to know is whether your employer *intends* for this rule to apply to you when you are not working.  And the only way to know that is to ask them.

Comment: Thank you Nate. I had already asked them (and they said "yes follow the rules when you're not on the clock"), but I came here because I was surprised at the legality of such a stance. Thanks.